# Integral k-scheme of locally finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry

An integral scheme of locally finite type over a field is always of finite type of the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, <s>take an infinite disjoint union of $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$.</s>  if it is not supposed to be separated. Just glue infinitely many copies of affines lines $\mathbb A^1$ along $\mathbb A^1\setminus \{ 0\}$.

Now even if $X$ is integral and separated, this is not necessarily true. 
See  [this example of BCnrd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34620/when-is-an-irreducible-scheme-quasi-compact/) at mathoverflow.

Comment: Dear QiL, I think it is not integral.

Comment: Dear @MakotoKato: you are absolutely right. I will edit.

Comment: Dear @QiL and MakotoKato Thank you very much. I understood.